# Convert double value with E-XX to “normal” value

Tags: vb6

I have the double value 
EX. 2.77555756156289E-17
-8.48087032699772E-18

I would like to convert it so that the E-XX is gone and zeros are used instead.
How would I do that , please?

Comment: When you use the value for output, you have to format the value as you like. If you do not specify a format, you may end with that E style. Format function: Format(yourVar, "###,###,###,##0.00"), for your plan (.... "0.0000000000000000000000")

Comment: Scientific notation is 'normal'. It's valuable to use it when the exponent gets larger.  After all, would you want to read "1.0E-50" or 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001?

Comment: You could also use `Round` to round off the value to a specific number of decimals (eg. 0). That way your values will turn to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,that works really well